# In firebase function the moment.js send wrong time in mailgun

Tags: javascript, firebase, momentjs

In firebase function i am sending email to users using **mailgun** on something trigger in firebase database with current time in **moment.js** like this,

```
 if (partnerEmail) {
    console.log(`online class email to partner`)
    let emailData = {
        recipient: partnerEmail,
        date: moment(date * 1000).format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
        time: moment(new Date()).format('h:mm:ss a'),
    };
    emailUtils.onlineClassPartner(emailData)
}
```

but the time property give wrong hours, minutes, second.

The current time is **05:48:00 PM** but in email it show **11:49:59 AM**

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that you have a timezone issue here.

In order to setup an appropriate time that will make sens for your users, you will probably need to get in which timezone they are (not ideal cause people are travelling), to display the date to them in the proper zone.

Email content is static and a date cannot be automatically formatted in the current user timezone.

When using `moment(new Date()).format('h:mm:ss a')` on your functions, it will be set at the date / hour of the timezone where you server is set.

You have two options:

1. Get for each of your user their timezone at a regular interval, and then format the date accordingly by [offsetting the difference with UTC](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/)
2. Specify to your users that the date showed to them is expressed at GMT +X (For example, if most of your clients are in China, then it might be obvious to display them a date that is expressed at GMT +8)

Comment: but if i pass the value from database that **date key**  timestamp it not showing the correct time